# Please synonymise [tez] with [apache-tez]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substrings) to be the synonym of [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substring)

[tez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tez) to be the synonym of [apache-tez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-tez)

I don't have enough rep for any. :/

Comment: First part of this request is completed